# Calculating RSSI value from physical X and Y coordinate

Tags: wifi, rssi

I would like to know is there is a way to calculate RSSI value from the distance between WiFi Access Point and mobile device? I am in need of this to build a mobile simulator to test the WiFi Access Point.

For Example: what would be the RSSI value if the mobile device is 4 meter away from the Access Point?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you have to know the radiated power of the Access Point immediately after the antenna. Therefore, you can apply the free space loss model and get a very rough estimate of what the distance is. But using this generic model it is almost sure that you will take a large estimate error.

In order to improve this technique you can perform measurements of the WiFi strength in your specific area and try to obtain the path loss exponent using the MMSE model.

I found a simple code snipset in Matlab for that: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/321904

but you can adapt it easily to Android.

In that way, you can use the single slope model instead of free space loss model just by replacing the square in the free space loss equation with your calculated one (path loss exponent).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-space_path_loss